# How to hide/protect Angular application (equivalent htpasswd)

Tags: angularjs, apache, basic-authentication

I tried to protect my application (the test environment) to hide it from curious with a htpasswd. Here is my architecture:

[AngularJS] -> [Apache Proxy] -> [Service]

The aim is to block people who has no password.

I tried first to add a htpasswd on my Apache Proxy at the highest level:

```
    <Location "/">
            AuthUserFile            /etc/apache2/passwords
            AuthName                "Forbidden"
            AuthType                Basic
            require                 valid-user
    </Location>
```

Problem: the prompt was fired at each time a request was made (don't know why).

I tried after to reduce the scope:

```
    <Location "/modules/user/">
            AuthUserFile            /etc/apache2/passwords
            AuthName                "Forbidden"
            AuthType                Basic
            require                 valid-user
    </Location>
```

It works because the call to this route is made at each request. Fine.

But now I created a new route : /modules/user/account. I fell in the first problem I have but worse: a prompt is always displayed, and never accepted. Apache in the logs says:

```
[Mon Nov 23 11:51:55.510434 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3043:tid 139650316363520] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 164.177.43.41:55888] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet), referer: https://test.mysite.com/
```

htpasswd is maybe the wrong way to protect my application, what should I do?

Thanks